# Selectors for content based routing in WMQ where the payload has a namespace

Tags: ibm-mq, mq

This question is related to Websphere MQ. I have a requirement where in I have to route messages based on the content of the message.

I know about the concept of selectors in WMQ subscriptions and I have also been successful in doing this based on the Message Headers (using MQRFH2 )

I now need to filter messages based on the payload which are XMLNSC and have a valid namespace associated with it.

Eg:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns0:test xmlns:ns0="abc.com/is/2009/schemas/envelope/">
  <flag>Y</flag>
</ns0:test>`

If I have to accept messages if the flag is 'Y' only, then how do I set the selector in my subscriptions?

Please let me know.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Any WebSphere MQ selection information must either be in the message header or a message property.  WMQ is tuned to move messages as far downstream as possible, as quickly as possible, and does not do anything with message payloads other than to deliver them. Any functionality based on data in the message body requires one of IBM's ESB solutions such as IIB, or else to write code to inspect the payload and take the appropriate action.

If at all possible, the application creating the messages should place the selection field into a message property.  If that isn't possible, a program can intercept the message, evaluate the payload and set the property, then re-queue the message.